# How to hyperparametrize Amazon SageMaker Training Jobs Console

Tags: h2o, training-data, amazon-sagemaker, automl

I'm trying to use de AWS SageMaker Training Jobs console to train a model with H2o.AutoMl.

I got stuck trying to set up Hyperparameters, specifically setting up the 'training' field.

```
{'classification': true, 'categorical_columns':'', 'target': 'label'}
```

[image]

I'm trying to set up a classification training job (1/0), and I believe that everything else on the setup page I can cope, but I don't know how to set up the 'training' field. My data is stored on S3 as a CSV file, as the algorithm requires.

My data has around 250000 columns, 4 out of them are categorical, one of them is the target, and the remainder is continuous variables (800 MB)

```
target column name = 'y'
categorical columns name = 'SIT','HOL','CTH','YTT'
```

I hope someone could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked I came across an explanation from [SageMaker examples.](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/aws_marketplace/using_algorithms/automl/AutoML_-_Train_multiple_models_in_parallel.ipynb)

{classification': 'true', 'categorical_columns': 'SIT','HOL','CTH','YTT','target': 'y'}.

Problem solved!